# How can I open xml file with drag and drop tool in android eclipse

Tags: android, xml

when i open xml file i cant see drag and drop tool for editing,instead i see the tool as a table containing Node and Content columns,how can i change that into normal drag and drop tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the XML layout file opened, at the bottom there should appear 2 tabs: Graphical Layout and .xml. Click on Graphical Layout.

If you don't have these tabs available then try right clicking on the XML file, select "Open with" and finally select "Android Layout Editor". Next you should be able to see the 2 tabs and the bottom.

You might want to update (if you have not yet) to the latest ADT tools as the Drag and drop tool has greatly improved.